# Control flash system from a c++ program

Tags: c++, qt, photo, photography

I'm currently building a c++ program (with Qt) to take picture from a camera device. This part is actualy done, now I need to control 8 flashs divided in two groups in an automatic way.

The flash I already use are from ELINCHROM http://www.elinchrom.com/ and this [device](http://www.elinchrom.com/product/EL-Skyport-USB-RX-SPEED.html#content) seems to be perfect for what I need but I could not find anywhere a way to control it from a different application than the one elinchrom propose.

Do you know if what I intend to do is even possible? If a solution exist with another brand I will also take it.

Thank you in advance for any replies, and please excuse my english.

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible; the driver guide states that the driver is really a USB serial port driver. That means you can probably reverse-engineer the protocol.